# Django API Rest protection layer without registration/login users

Tags: android, ios, django, django-authentication

I need to implement a Django REST back-end for mobile apps (iOS and Android).

For this app is not required any registration/login operations but I would to add some security level to protect the REST API from external access.

I have an API to register the device for push notifications at startup on the mobile application: when the user starts the application will need to register the device sending the information about the push notification + more info of the device (language, token push app version ...)

How can I provide a protection system for the APIs (for example, using a token or something like that)?

Comment: Check out the Django Rest Framework's Token Authentication: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication

Answer (score 0):

See [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) for basic token authentication.

You can also try [Django OAuth Toolkit](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit) package which provides OAuth 2.0 support.

Comment: I not have a concept of logged user. Is possible to use Django OAuth Toolkit  only like Rest API protection? In my system the user can use the app without registration/login so I not have to create a django user to use basic auth, token authentication etc etc

Comment: To my understanding, you want to send the unique information of a phone (for example the uuid of an iphone) to the server, and the server register with this information and return a token?